# Redbean MySql insert error

Tags: php, redbean

I have the following code:

```
Array
(
    [title] => asdas
    [question] => dasdsa
    [gender] => 
    [age] => 
    [description] => 
    [imageUrl] => 
    [plan_id] => 2
    [plan_type] => special
    [plan_price] => 199
    [specialty_id] => 7
    [specialty] => Cardiologist
)
```

I'm getting error for specialty:

```
Error


RedBeanPHP\RedException Object
(
    [message:protected] => Cannot cast to bean.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/rb/rb.php
    [line:protected] => 2203
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/rb/rb.php
                    [line] => 2414
                    [function] => __set
                    [class] => RedBeanPHP\OODBBean
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => specialty
                            [1] => asdsad
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/class/crud.php
                    [line] => 52
                    [function] => offsetSet
                    [class] => RedBeanPHP\OODBBean
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => specialty
                            [1] => asdsad
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/validate/question/step2.php

                    [line] => 37
                    [function] => insert
                    [class] => crud
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => question
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => asdas
                                    [question] => dasdsa
                                    [gender] => 
                                    [age] => 
                                    [description] => 
                                    [imageUrl] => 
                                    [plan_id] => 2
                                    [plan_type] => special
                                    [plan_price] => 199
                                    [specialty_id] => 7
                                    [specialty] => asdsad
                                    [contributor] => dinesh
                                    [created_by] => 1
                                    [ip_address] => ::1
                                    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

I spent more than 1 hour trying to fix this, and I'm still not able to fix it.

Comment: Assuming your code is PHP, you need to enclose string with brackets don't you ? Also show us line `2203` of `rb.php` ?

Comment: This is my params

Array
(
    [title] => asdas
    [question] => dasdsa
    [gender] => 
    [age] => 
    [description] => 
    [imageUrl] => 
    [plan_id] => 2
    [plan_type] => special
    [plan_price] => 199
    [specialty_id] => 7
    [specialty] => Cardiologist
)

Comment: If you remove the specialty param its working properly .

Comment: Did you try enclosing your string with brackets and add commas ? The error you get in unclear to me. `Array ( [title] => "asdas", [question] => "dasdsa", [gender] => "", [age] => "", [description] => "", [imageUrl] => "", [plan_id] => 2, [plan_type] => "special", [plan_price] => 199, [specialty_id] => 7, [specialty] => "Cardiologist" );`

Comment: s i tried. the issue on specialty .

Comment: <br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'RedBeanPHP\RedException' with message 'Cannot cast to bean.'
 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/rb/rb.php:2203
Stack trace:#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/rb/rb.php(2414): RedBeanPHP\OODBBean-&gt;__set('specialty'
, 'asdsad')

Comment: Show us lines 2203 and 2414 of rb.php with in an edit to your post.

Comment: Maybe this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112383/redbean-nested-beans-whats-going-wrong can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to save an array instead of a bean. Always you call `R::store()` you have to pass a bean.

Redbean creates database structure for you, you just need to switch to fluid mode `R::freeze(false);`

for ex:

```
R::freeze(false);

$plan = R::dispense('plan');
$plan->description = 'Plan 1';
$bean->planprice = 199.99;

$plantype = R::dispense('plantype');//without underline, ok?!!!
$plantype->description = 'Standard';

$specialty = R::dispense('specialty');
$specialty->description = 'Cardiologist';

$bean = R::dispense('tablename');
$bean->title = 'asdas';
$bean->question = 'dasdsa';
$bean->gender = 1;//1 - Male; 2 - Female;
$bean->age = 39; 
$bean->description = 'bla bla bla';
$bean->imageurl = 'http://urltotheimage/img.jpg';
$bean->plan = $plan;
$bean->plantype = $plantype;
$bean->specialty = $specialty;

R::store($bean);
```

When you store a $bean, redbean store every others bean you created (`$plan, $plantype, $specialty`) with attr name with `_id` in the end of column name.

If you have a given id, you dont need to save `$plan` as a bean (if you already have the registry stored on database) you just have to pass

`$bean->plan_id = $givenid;`

Redbean is an amazing orm tool, but you have to deepen inside it's site to work with it;

Comment: I want to use specialty_text ?

Comment: same concept am using other table its inserting correctly without error  on specialty field.

Comment: You can't use `_` in table names, but no problem using it on column name, to help you, search for method `runQuery` inside rb.php and log  `$sql` and `$bindings` variables, than you can check what redbean is executing on database